# Build Ionic with Adobe Analytics

Tags: ionic-framework, adobe-analytics

I use ionic framework

My Ionic and Cordova version

Ionic version: 3.20.0

Cordova version: 8.0.0

```
    ↓--------↓cmd instruction↓--------↓

    C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin>i> npm install -g ionic cordova

    C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin>ionic start IonicApp2 tabs

    ? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes

    ? Install the free Ionic Pro SDK and connect your app? No

    C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin>cd IonicApp2

    C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin\IonicApp2>ionic cordova plugin add adobe-mobile-services


    ↑--------↑cmd instruction↑--------↑


Edit

C:\Users\Lawliet.Lin\IonicApp2\src\pages\home\home.html

Add
<button style="height:200px; width:200px" onclick = "window.ADB.trackState('login page', {'user':'john','remember':'true'});">sampleHit</button>
```

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

[image: Sample Image]

I have missed out no vital steps .?

Comment: On my ionic app, I ended up adding the regular adobe Mobile SDK to get launch/app-specific details, then using DTM for all my state/user-action-specific actions. I didn't mess with the cordova plugin at all.

Comment: Finally, I have the reason for finding the problem.
I used "ionic serve" to view it.
In fact, you can use instructions
"ionic cordova emulate android" or "ionic cordova build android"
Execute the project to the mobile device and collect the data in Adobe Analytics.